# .Net Core Contoso Tutorial During migrations and error is encountered with an object already in the database

Tags: .net-core

While studying and following along with the migration section, I had done the initial, then followed it up with the next two migrations as shown. On the last migration an error of the "course" is already in the database. Exact error "There is already an object named 'Course' in the database." I removed all migrations and re-did the shown migrations, each time ending with the same error.

Why does this type of error occur? A

nd how to completely remove all migrations (my migration folder was blank) so that one can move forward with the next migration. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially a big topic to fit into a single answer. I will try to give you an overview, background and advice. Further reading will be required to get a full understanding of how Entity Framework should be utilised. I will mostly cover Migrations, as that is the main thrust of your question.

**OVERVIEW**

Entity Framework Migrations offer the ability to rollback the changes made to a database, back to the schema of the database that is contained in a specified Migration; e.g. to undo schema changes by returning the database to a previous schema - and also to return it to its original state.

Note that data loss can occur when applying or rolling back Migrations, but in your scenario this is possibly not important.

The command to return a database to a specific Migration is:

```
     Update-Database -TargetMigration:"migration_name"
```

The command to return to the initial, original state of the database is:

```
     Update-Database –TargetMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

Entity Framework also has the optional concepts of `Database Initialization` and  `Initialization Strategies`, that allow a developer to specify that the database should only be created once, or dropped and created each time an application is run, depending if their `Code First` model has changed. Please refer to [these  tutorials](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) for more in depth coverage of Database Initialization.

As you say you have no Migration files in your Migrations folder, let us continue...

**BACKGROUND**

When you first run the `Enable-Migrations`command, it will create a class that is used for managing subsequent application of Migrations.

When you generate your first Migration, by executing, for example:

```
    Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

This will create an `InitialCreate` file within your Migrations folder, that  contains the initial schema, according to your class model that will be persisted by Entity Framework. The example name `InitialCreate` is optional and can be anything you wish - it is simply a label that can be referred to later.

Subsequently, when you issue an `Add-Migration` command, further Migrations are created to apply schema changes related to your classes; they will be added to your Migrations folder, but, **not** yet applied to the database.

The Migrations can then be applied to your database by issuing the `Update-Database` command. If executed without parameters, the database schema is updated to the schema defined by the latest Migration.

If you are following the Contoso tutorial correctly, you *should* have several Migrations, one of which contains the word 'Initial' in its name, as part of the convention.

**ADVICE**

1. If you do not see these, it is likely that you have not *initialised* Migrations, by issuing the command `Enable-Migrations`.
2. After executing Update-Database for the first time, verify this also creates a database table named `__MigrationHistory` - this tracks the schema versions and Migrations that have been applied.
3. You have possibly applied Migrations in an incorrect order, and it now does not match your class structure, or, is out of sync with the schema tracking within the database.
4. In your current circumstances, as you are following a tutorial, it is probably best to delete your database, and recreate it following the steps outlined by Microsoft, paying special attention to the output from `Enable-Migrations`, `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` commands, verifying the database schema at each step.

**REFERENCE**

For reference, the overview of how Migrations should be utilised, can be found  [on MSDN here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)

A walkthrough of using Migrations with MVC can be found [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)